# Combine two heatmaps in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'm facing the problem with two heatmaps in seaborn and matplotlib.

My problem is, that I need to combine two heatmaps to show main differences. I have some data points (x, y) some points are for red heatmap some are for blue. The goal is combination of these and it should looks like this.

**Goal heatmap:**
[image: Goal]

Now I have this two maps:

**Map 1:**
[image]

**Map 2:**
[image]

My code looks like this.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.head(10)

red = data.loc[data.type == "red"]
blue = data.loc[data.type == "blue"]

ax = sns.kdeplot(blue.x_pos, blue.y_pos,
                  cmap="Blues", n_levels=15, shade=True, shade_lowest=False, legend=False)

ax = sns.kdeplot(red.x_pos, red.y_pos,
                  cmap="Reds", n_levels=15, shade=True, shade_lowest=False, legend=False)

plt.ylim(-300, 300)
plt.xlim(-300, 300)


ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])

plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

**CSV FILE**

```
x_pos,y_pos,type
108,-204,red
108,-168,red
108,-228,red
108,-192,red
108,-144,red
108,108,red
108,180,red
108,192,red
108,228,red
108,-240,red
108,-216,red
108,-180,red
108,-156,blue
108,-132,red
108,-120,red
108,-108,blue
108,-96,red
108,-84,red
108,-72,red
108,-60,blue
108,-48,red
108,-24,blue
108,0,red
108,72,red
108,120,red
108,132,red
108,144,red
108,156,blue
108,204,red
108,240,red
108,-12,red
108,168,blue
108,216,blue
108,252,blue
96,-156,red
96,-36,red
96,-192,red
96,-72,red
96,-48,red
96,144,red
96,204,red
96,-240,red
96,-228,red
96,-204,red
96,-168,red
96,-144,blue
96,-120,blue
96,-96,blue
96,-12,red
96,12,blue
96,36,red
96,72,red
96,96,red
96,108,red
96,168,blue
96,192,red
96,228,blue
96,252,blue
96,-108,red
96,-60,red
96,48,red
96,156,blue
96,180,blue
96,-252,red
96,-180,red
96,-132,blue
96,120,red
-108,-168,red
-108,108,red
-108,-240,blue
-108,-228,blue
-108,-216,blue
-108,-204,blue
-108,-156,red
-108,-144,red
-108,-120,red
-108,-108,blue
-108,-96,red
-108,-84,red
-108,-60,red
-108,0,blue
-108,36,blue
-108,48,red
-108,60,red
-108,120,red
-108,144,red
-108,180,red
-108,192,blue
-108,204,blue
-108,240,red
-108,-192,blue
-108,-180,blue
-108,-36,blue
-108,-12,red
-108,24,blue
-108,156,red
-108,168,red
-108,252,red
-108,-132,red
-108,-24,red
-108,72,red
-108,84,blue
-108,264,red
-108,96,red
-108,228,red
-96,-156,red
-96,180,red
-96,-240,blue
-96,-204,red
-96,-192,blue
-96,-180,blue
-96,-168,red
-96,-96,red
-96,-48,red
-96,-24,red
-96,0,red
-96,72,blue
-96,84,blue
-96,96,blue
-96,132,red
-96,192,blue
-96,228,blue
-96,-252,blue
-96,-216,red
-96,-144,red
-96,48,red
-96,108,red
-96,-132,red
-96,-60,blue
-96,36,blue
-96,-84,blue
132,168,red
132,-216,red
132,-192,red
132,-168,blue
132,-156,blue
132,-120,red
132,-84,red
132,-48,blue
132,-36,red
132,0,red
132,24,red
132,84,red
132,120,red
132,144,red
132,192,red
132,216,red
132,240,red
132,-240,red
132,-228,red
132,-180,red
132,48,red
132,156,blue
132,228,red
132,96,red
132,108,red
132,-132,red
132,-24,red
132,60,red
228,36,red
228,48,blue
228,-72,blue
228,-60,red
228,-36,blue
228,-12,blue
228,0,blue
228,24,blue
228,72,blue
228,84,red
228,96,red
228,192,red
228,204,red
228,240,red
228,-108,red
228,-84,blue
228,-192,red
228,-156,red
228,60,blue
228,180,red
228,156,red
228,12,blue
144,72,red
144,-240,red
144,-192,red
144,-180,red
144,-156,blue
144,0,blue
144,24,red
144,36,red
144,48,red
144,84,blue
144,108,red
144,216,red
144,228,red
144,-276,red
144,-228,red
144,-144,red
144,-132,blue
144,-48,red
144,120,blue
144,156,red
144,192,red
144,-72,red
144,-12,red
144,-84,red
144,60,blue
216,-228,red
216,12,red
216,-240,red
216,-168,red
216,-108,blue
216,-96,blue
216,-48,blue
216,-36,blue
216,0,blue
216,60,blue
216,84,red
216,108,red
216,180,red
216,-216,red
216,48,blue
216,96,blue
216,168,red
216,-72,blue
216,-12,red
216,-156,red
216,228,blue
156,-156,red
156,60,red
156,-144,red
156,-84,red
156,-48,red
156,-36,red
156,-24,red
156,84,red
156,180,red
156,192,red
156,204,blue
156,228,red
156,-252,red
156,-240,red
156,-108,blue
156,0,blue
156,240,red
156,-216,red
156,-192,blue
156,-60,red
156,48,blue
156,132,red
156,252,red
156,276,red
-216,0,red
-216,84,red
-216,-276,red
-216,-144,blue
-216,-84,blue
-216,-36,red
-216,-12,red
-216,12,red
-216,24,blue
-216,60,red
-216,108,red
-216,120,red
-216,-156,red
-216,-48,blue
-216,36,blue
-216,72,red
-216,96,red
-216,-240,blue
-216,-72,blue
-216,132,red
-216,264,red
-192,-216,red
-192,-144,red
-192,-120,red
-192,-108,red
-192,-36,red
-192,-12,red
-192,24,red
-192,36,red
-192,72,blue
-192,96,red
-192,216,red
-192,-48,blue
-192,12,red
-192,48,red
-192,84,red
-192,108,red
-192,276,red
-192,-252,red
-192,-192,red
-192,132,red
-192,156,blue
-192,-180,red
-192,264,red
-156,-216,red
-156,-156,red
-156,-132,red
-156,-120,blue
-156,-84,red
-156,-72,red
-156,-12,red
-156,0,red
-156,12,red
-156,36,blue
-156,48,red
-156,132,blue
-156,156,red
-156,180,red
-156,192,blue
-156,-192,red
-156,-168,red
-156,-108,blue
-156,108,red
-156,144,red
-156,-276,red
-156,-96,red
-156,-24,red
-156,120,blue
-156,-36,blue
-156,216,red
-156,228,red
-156,264,red
-144,204,blue
-144,-192,blue
-144,-156,blue
-144,-120,red
-144,-108,blue
-144,-72,red
-144,-60,red
-144,24,red
-144,48,red
-144,96,red
-144,156,red
-144,168,red
-144,-276,red
-144,-36,red
-144,-24,red
-144,0,red
-144,72,red
-144,216,blue
-144,-84,blue
-144,108,blue
-144,-252,red
-144,-180,blue
192,-12,blue
192,-228,red
192,-144,red
192,-48,red
192,-24,blue
192,36,red
192,84,blue
192,144,red
192,156,red
192,180,red
192,228,blue
192,-108,blue
192,24,blue
192,216,red
192,240,red
192,-240,red
192,-204,red
192,-60,blue
-180,-228,blue
-180,-132,red
-180,-120,red
-180,-96,red
-180,-72,red
-180,-48,blue
-180,-36,red
-180,-12,red
-180,96,red
-180,156,blue
-180,-240,red
-180,-144,blue
-180,-24,blue
-180,36,red
-180,48,red
-180,132,red
-180,-168,red
-180,-84,blue
-180,12,blue
-180,168,red
-180,204,red
-180,-264,red
-180,24,blue
-120,108,red
-120,-240,blue
-120,-192,red
-120,-156,red
-120,-132,red
-120,-120,red
-120,-108,red
-120,-96,red
-120,48,red
-120,96,red
-120,144,red
-120,168,red
-120,192,red
-120,-84,red
-120,0,red
-120,24,red
-120,120,red
-120,156,red
-120,180,red
-120,216,red
-120,252,red
-120,-36,red
-120,36,red
-120,60,blue
-120,132,red
-120,240,blue
120,-240,red
120,-216,red
120,-192,red
120,-180,red
120,-84,blue
120,-36,red
120,108,red
120,192,blue
120,204,red
120,228,red
120,-264,blue
120,-204,red
120,36,red
120,72,red
120,96,blue
120,0,red
120,-252,red
120,-168,red
120,-156,blue
120,-120,red
120,-60,red
120,24,blue
120,216,blue
120,-108,red
120,144,blue
-204,204,red
-204,-264,red
-204,-216,red
-204,-96,blue
-204,24,red
-204,72,red
-204,96,red
-204,144,red
-204,168,red
-204,240,red
-204,-168,red
-204,-132,red
-204,-60,blue
-204,-48,red
-204,-36,blue
-204,0,red
-204,48,red
-204,108,red
-204,156,red
-204,-84,blue
-204,-24,blue
-204,60,blue
-204,-252,blue
-204,12,red
-132,-132,red
-132,-216,red
-132,-144,red
-132,-60,red
-132,-24,red
-132,-12,red
-132,0,blue
-132,24,red
-132,36,red
-132,48,red
-132,72,blue
-132,84,red
-132,168,red
-132,-84,red
-132,-36,blue
-132,96,red
-132,132,red
-132,-204,red
-132,-96,red
-132,-48,blue
-132,156,blue
-132,192,blue
-132,-192,red
-132,-108,blue
-132,-72,blue
180,-252,red
180,-204,red
180,-84,blue
180,-48,red
180,0,blue
180,144,red
180,180,red
180,192,blue
180,240,red
180,228,red
180,-264,red
180,-132,blue
180,36,blue
180,-36,red
180,84,blue
180,216,red
180,-228,red
180,168,red
204,60,red
204,-120,red
204,-108,red
204,-48,red
204,-36,blue
204,-24,red
204,0,blue
204,12,blue
204,108,red
204,156,red
204,180,red
204,228,red
204,-228,red
204,-192,red
204,-84,blue
204,48,blue
204,-240,red
204,-180,red
204,-96,red
204,240,blue
204,252,red
204,-276,red
204,-72,blue
240,60,blue
240,-36,blue
240,-24,blue
240,24,blue
240,36,blue
240,48,red
240,144,red
240,156,red
240,168,red
240,-72,red
240,72,red
240,-132,red
240,108,red
240,84,blue
240,-120,red
-228,-216,red
-228,-108,red
-228,-84,red
-228,-36,blue
-228,-24,red
-228,-12,red
-228,12,blue
-228,24,blue
-228,72,red
-228,48,red
-228,-48,blue
-228,36,blue
-228,84,blue
-228,108,red
-228,-180,red
-168,12,red
-168,-132,red
-168,-120,blue
-168,-84,blue
-168,0,red
-168,60,red
-168,84,blue
-168,216,red
-168,276,red
-168,24,red
-168,-240,blue
-168,-228,blue
-168,36,red
-168,96,red
-168,120,blue
-168,168,red
-168,-144,red
-168,-12,red
-168,48,red
-168,-252,red
-168,-72,blue
-168,156,blue
-240,24,red
-240,-132,blue
-240,-24,red
-240,0,red
-240,36,blue
-240,60,blue
-240,72,blue
-240,228,red
-240,-60,red
-240,48,blue
-240,-96,red
-240,-48,blue
168,-252,red
168,-228,red
168,-216,red
168,-72,red
168,48,red
168,84,red
168,120,red
168,168,red
168,180,red
168,240,red
168,228,red
168,-132,red
168,144,red
168,192,red
168,-108,blue
168,108,blue
168,156,blue
168,0,blue
168,132,red
-84,-120,red
-84,-96,red
-84,-60,red
-84,-24,red
-84,0,red
-84,84,red
-84,132,red
-84,144,red
-84,228,red
-84,252,red
-84,-192,red
-84,96,red
-84,108,red
-84,-276,red
-84,-204,red
-84,60,red
-84,192,red
84,240,red
84,-216,red
84,-108,blue
84,-72,red
84,-48,red
84,-36,blue
12,-168,red
12,-132,red
12,168,red
12,-216,red
12,-12,red
12,0,red
12,204,red
12,72,red
-252,0,red
-252,24,red
-252,36,red
-252,60,red
-24,-228,red
-24,-216,red
-24,96,red
-24,180,red
-24,-240,red
-24,-132,red
-24,-12,red
-24,72,red
-24,108,red
-24,144,red
-12,-108,red
-12,132,red
-12,228,red
-12,-156,red
-12,156,red
-12,216,red
36,-264,red
36,-228,red
36,-108,red
36,-12,red
36,156,red
36,180,red
36,-144,red
36,-36,red
36,96,red
-72,-204,red
-72,-24,red
-72,0,red
-72,-240,red
-72,-96,red
-72,24,red
-72,216,red
-36,-156,red
-36,-72,red
-36,168,red
-36,144,red
-36,156,red
48,-60,red
48,144,red
48,216,red
48,-36,red
48,168,red
48,-216,red
60,-84,red
60,264,red
60,-276,red
60,168,red
-60,-144,red
-60,-48,red
-60,240,red
-60,-96,red
-48,-228,red
-48,180,red
-48,-60,red
-48,192,red
0,84,red
0,204,red
0,-36,red
0,-240,red
0,192,red
0,-12,red
0,120,red
0,264,red
24,-180,red
24,-252,red
24,-240,red
24,-24,red
252,96,red
252,216,red
252,180,red
72,-252,red
108,-36,blue
108,12,blue
108,36,blue
108,24,blue
108,84,blue
108,276,blue
108,96,blue
108,-264,blue
-96,204,blue
-96,-36,blue
-96,60,blue
-96,-264,blue
-96,-120,blue
-96,240,blue
-96,252,blue
96,-84,blue
96,60,blue
96,264,blue
96,-264,blue
96,-216,blue
-108,-252,blue
228,-24,blue
228,120,blue
228,132,blue
228,-120,blue
228,-264,blue
228,-180,blue
228,-132,blue
228,252,blue
228,-96,blue
240,-192,blue
240,-180,blue
240,-108,blue
240,-12,blue
240,0,blue
240,12,blue
240,132,blue
240,192,blue
240,228,blue
240,-168,blue
132,-60,blue
132,12,blue
132,132,blue
132,-108,blue
132,264,blue
132,-276,blue
156,-72,blue
156,-168,blue
156,-120,blue
156,36,blue
156,108,blue
156,144,blue
156,168,blue
156,216,blue
156,-204,blue
156,-180,blue
156,-132,blue
156,-12,blue
156,120,blue
156,264,blue
192,-84,blue
192,-216,blue
192,-192,blue
192,-132,blue
192,-120,blue
192,48,blue
192,60,blue
192,96,blue
192,-264,blue
192,-252,blue
192,108,blue
192,132,blue
192,-96,blue
192,192,blue
216,-120,blue
216,-84,blue
216,-60,blue
216,144,blue
216,216,blue
216,120,blue
216,192,blue
216,204,blue
216,240,blue
216,24,blue
-240,-204,blue
-240,-120,blue
-240,-84,blue
-240,-216,blue
-240,96,blue
-240,144,blue
-240,-192,blue
180,-24,blue
180,-72,blue
180,-12,blue
180,24,blue
180,96,blue
180,156,blue
180,132,blue
180,-180,blue
180,48,blue
180,-144,blue
180,276,blue
-216,-216,blue
-216,-60,blue
-216,192,blue
-216,-192,blue
-216,-168,blue
-216,216,blue
-216,252,blue
120,-72,blue
120,-12,blue
120,132,blue
120,156,blue
120,-228,blue
120,180,blue
120,120,blue
120,-96,blue
144,-168,blue
144,-36,blue
144,12,blue
144,180,blue
144,-108,blue
144,264,blue
144,-252,blue
144,-120,blue
144,-96,blue
144,144,blue
144,252,blue
-144,-48,blue
-144,84,blue
-144,240,blue
-144,-240,blue
-144,-144,blue
-144,-96,blue
-144,36,blue
-144,144,blue
-144,60,blue
-204,-156,blue
-204,-120,blue
-204,-108,blue
-204,-72,blue
-204,132,blue
-204,-240,blue
-204,-228,blue
-204,-144,blue
-204,228,blue
-204,264,blue
-204,192,blue
-132,-180,blue
-132,60,blue
-132,120,blue
-132,228,blue
-132,-120,blue
-132,204,blue
-132,216,blue
-132,-240,blue
-132,-228,blue
-192,-156,blue
-192,-228,blue
-192,-168,blue
-192,192,blue
-192,-84,blue
-192,-240,blue
-192,228,blue
-168,-192,blue
-168,-180,blue
-168,-36,blue
-168,72,blue
-168,228,blue
-168,-96,blue
-168,-60,blue
-168,108,blue
-168,144,blue
-168,-156,blue
-168,132,blue
-156,-240,blue
-156,-228,blue
-156,-180,blue
-156,-60,blue
-156,204,blue
-156,-204,blue
-156,168,blue
-156,-48,blue
-156,84,blue
-156,60,blue
168,252,blue
168,-276,blue
168,-60,blue
168,60,blue
168,264,blue
168,-144,blue
168,-120,blue
168,-12,blue
168,-264,blue
168,-84,blue
-228,-120,blue
-228,-60,blue
-228,144,blue
-228,-96,blue
-228,96,blue
-228,120,blue
-228,156,blue
-228,-156,blue
-228,60,blue
-228,216,blue
-180,84,blue
-180,192,blue
-180,-204,blue
-180,60,blue
-180,-276,blue
-180,-156,blue
-180,264,blue
204,-204,blue
204,-156,blue
204,-132,blue
204,84,blue
204,120,blue
204,132,blue
204,144,blue
204,-216,blue
204,24,blue
204,-264,blue
204,96,blue
-120,-180,blue
-120,204,blue
-120,228,blue
-120,-12,blue
-120,72,blue
-120,-204,blue
-120,-48,blue
84,-132,blue
84,-12,blue
84,24,blue
84,84,blue
84,156,blue
84,180,blue
84,192,blue
84,-228,blue
84,-156,blue
84,48,blue
84,-264,blue
-84,216,blue
-252,72,blue
-252,108,blue
-252,-60,blue
12,216,blue
12,-264,blue
12,-228,blue
12,60,blue
12,108,blue
-60,-192,blue
-60,-252,blue
-60,-204,blue
-60,-156,blue
-60,-36,blue
36,0,blue
36,48,blue
36,120,blue
36,144,blue
36,-204,blue
36,84,blue
36,-72,blue
-12,-72,blue
-12,120,blue
-12,-84,blue
-48,-216,blue
-48,168,blue
-48,-168,blue
-48,228,blue
-48,144,blue
-48,0,blue
-36,108,blue
-36,-204,blue
-36,-132,blue
-24,-204,blue
-24,60,blue
-24,240,blue
0,180,blue
0,-120,blue
24,48,blue
24,-228,blue
24,-204,blue
48,36,blue
48,-228,blue
48,-24,blue
48,72,blue
60,192,blue
60,0,blue
60,12,blue
60,228,blue
252,-84,blue
252,-72,blue
252,36,blue
252,-60,blue
252,-48,blue
72,228,blue
72,84,blue
72,156,blue
72,12,blue
```

Does exist some way how to do it in seaborn?
Thank you

Comment: did you try to pass `ax=ax` to the second `kdeplot` call? It should draw on the specified axes... however I'm not sure whether the final result you'll obtain will be what you want.

Comment: Uhm, apparently you should not need that. [The documentation page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) at the very bottom has an example that seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta When I try it it looks still the same. I see only second kdeplot. First is under and is not visible.

Comment: If you want to show the main differences, can't you just compute `difference = red-blue` and plot the heatmap of the difference?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Yes, I used this example. But I need somehow show only differences. This way I see only second graph because first is hidden under second.

Comment: @DanielR. This is exactly what I need but can't find any info in docs how to do it.

Comment: @Roman Šimr `red = data.loc[data.type == "red"]` `blue = data.loc[data.type == "blue"]` `difference = red-blue` `sns.kdeplot()` on difference :) You may have to compute it on the individual `x` and `y` columns though. EDIT: Can you post a samle in csv format or other easy to copy format of the data you are working on?

Comment: @DanielR. when I add difference = red-blue  into my code, graph looks still the same. Could you please add this code into my and add it there as answer? Thank you so much.

Comment: @DanielR. x_pos,y_pos,type
108,-204,red
108,-168,blue
108,-228,red
108,-192,red

Comment: @Roman Šimr We can help you I think, but you need to provide us samples from your dataset in a format from which we can copy/pase. Please edit the Question above by adding a new (CTRL+K) block containing the data written in the code. I'll meanwhile clean it manually, but you should prepare it in a usable format.

Comment: @DanielR. I have added it into Question.

Comment: This is clear now, thank you. The question is thus, rather than just plotting graphs: How do I compute the difference between two gaussian/bivariate kde's? It takes a bit more knowledge of calculus than I possess, but i'll try to look into it. Meanwhile, a [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this works, it's blatantly copied/readapted from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

Put your data in 'data.csv'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# import seaborn as sns # No longer used
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
red_df = df[df['type']=='red']
blue_df = df[df['type']=='blue']

def compute_KDE_from_pos(x_pos,y_pos):

    xmin = x_pos.min()
    xmax = x_pos.max()
    ymin = y_pos.min()
    ymax = y_pos.max()

    X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
    positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
    values = np.vstack([x_pos, y_pos])
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
    Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

    return Z

Z_red = compute_KDE_from_pos(red_df.x_pos,red_df.y_pos)
Z_blue = compute_KDE_from_pos(blue_df.x_pos,blue_df.y_pos)
Z_diff = Z_red-Z_blue

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z_diff), cmap='RdBu',
           extent=[df.x_pos.min(), df.x_pos.max(), df.y_pos.min(), df.y_pos.max()])
ax.plot(red_df.x_pos, red_df.y_pos, 'r.', markersize=2)
ax.plot(blue_df.x_pos, blue_df.y_pos, 'b.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([df.x_pos.min(), df.x_pos.max()])
ax.set_ylim([df.y_pos.min(), df.y_pos.max()])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I wrote a cleaner version of the code. You may still want to check whether the colour map used corresponds to what you expect, or whether you must invert the reds with the blues. Either ways, this code answers the question.

Comment: Sorry I was working, and had already imported `numpy as np` in the namespace. I have added the missing import in the code, try now. Also seaborn is no longer used, so I am removing it now.

Comment: Thank you. Last question. Is possible to get white background transparent, or make look more like kdeplot. Thank you

Comment: Or make background different colour than white?

Comment: The "background" is not a background, it corresponds to the values of Z_diff where Z_red == Z_blue. You can anyways change the map colour by passing a different value to `cmap='RdBu'`, in `ax.imshow()`. The zeroes will remain zeroes though, even if represented with a different colour.

Comment: [This](https://ibb.co/meXUEp) is the output of the script if you pass `cmap='RdYlBu'` to `ax.imshow()` for example, the values closer to zero are now represented in yellow.

Comment: Please I have more questions about this kind of problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791324/adding-importance-of-points-in-matplotlib-heat-map